# grails 2.3 spock integration test No WebApplicationContext found error

Tags: grails

I just upgraded an existing App from Grails 2.2.4 to 2.3.0. All spock Integration tests are broken since then. The error message I got is shown below. There is no problem running unit test or run-app. Thanks advance for any advice.

```java
| Error Fatal error running tests: No WebApplicationContext found: no ContextLoaderListener registered? (NOTE: Stack trace has been filtered. Use --verbose to see entire trace.)
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No WebApplicationContext found: no ContextLoaderListener registered?
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(WebApplicationContextUtils.java:90)
    at grails.util.Holders.getApplicationContext(Holders.java:78)
    at _GrailsTest_groovy$_run_closure1.doCall(_GrailsTest_groovy:95)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy:90)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.this$4$withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
    at TestApp$_run_closure1.doCall(TestApp.groovy:32)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy:90)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.this$4$withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
    at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure5.doCall(Gant.groovy:381)
    at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy:415)
    at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy)
    at gant.Gant.withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy:427)
    at gant.Gant.this$2$withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy)
    at gant.Gant$this$2$withBuildListeners.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at gant.Gant.dispatch(Gant.groovy:415)
    at gant.Gant.this$2$dispatch(Gant.groovy)
    at gant.Gant.invokeMethod(Gant.groovy)
    at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:591)
    at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:590)
| Error Fatal error running tests: No WebApplicationContext found: no ContextLoaderListener registered?
```

Answer (score 0):

You no longer need to add the Spock plugin to your projects for grails >= 2.3.

Simply create Spock specifications as before and they will be run as unit tests. In fact, don't install the Spock plugin, otherwise your specifications will run twice and potentially fail. This also means that the spock test type no longer exists.

Specifications and JUnit tests run as the same type now.

Comment: Thank for the suggestion but I already removed the spock dependencies and use the default one from Grails 2.3.3

Answer (score 0):

OK. I figured this out a while ago.

The reason is I tried to mock servletcontext in the integration test while it is already provided for in Grails 2.3.2. After removing the mocked servletContext, everything worked lie before.